# How to get a nicely formatted query from nHiberhate?

Tags: nhibernate

I would like nHibernate to give me a clean query in my logs.  Rather than a single line like this:

```
select project2x0_.proj_id as proj1_10_0_, projwbs1_.wbs_id as wbs1_11_1_, project2x0_.proj_short_name as proj2_10_0_, project2x0_.project_flag as project3_10_0_, projwbs1_.wbs_name as wbs2_11_1_, projwbs1_.wbs_short_name as wbs3_11_1_, projwbs1_.proj_id as proj4_11_1_, projwbs1_.proj_id as proj4_0__, projwbs1_.wbs_id as wbs1_0__ from project project2x0_ left outer join projwbs projwbs1_ on project2x0_.proj_id=projwbs1_.proj_id where @p0=1;@p0 = True [Type: Boolean (0)]
```

I would much prefer to see it in a more readable form such as this:

```
select project2x0_.proj_id as proj1_10_0_
, projwbs1_.wbs_id as wbs1_11_1_
, project2x0_.proj_short_name as proj2_10_0_
, project2x0_.project_flag as project3_10_0_
, projwbs1_.wbs_name as wbs2_11_1_
, projwbs1_.wbs_short_name as wbs3_11_1_
, projwbs1_.proj_id as proj4_11_1_
, projwbs1_.proj_id as proj4_0__
, projwbs1_.wbs_id as wbs1_0__ 
from project project2x0_ 
left outer join projwbs projwbs1_
  on project2x0_.proj_id=projwbs1_.proj_id 
where @p0=1;
```

;@p0 = True [Type: Boolean (0)]

The specific fields could all be on one line, that's fine.  But I really like to see the FROM, and JOIN, and WHERE statements pulled out.

I would like this to be in the log4net output, not via some 3rd party tool.

Any ideas?

Comment: logs tend to be 1-record-per-line. switching to a multi-line setup changes the game.

Comment: More like one string per output call.  whether the string has returns in it should not matter to the log appender

Comment: but it'll matter to a log reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting "format_sql" property to true on Configuration object gives an output similiar to what you want.